# What resource(s) are consumed by async calls on linux / node.js

Tags: node.js, linux, asynchronous, resources

Trying to find some metrics to monitor the health of a linux/node.js system making large number of async calls.

At times these servers fall over and response times run into the 10's of minutes.  I know I can monitor response times but would like to find a metric(s) about oustanding async calls.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably need is the async_hooks module. Note that it is still 
experimental. It provides an API to register callbacks tracking the lifetime of asynchronous resources created inside a Node.js application.

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/async_hooks.html